# What is the asymptotic time to sort multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, big-o

Consider the DataFrame df and the sorting using two columns in pandas

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5],[1,2,4,5,5,5,43,6,4]]).T
df.columns = ['A','B']
df.sort_values(by=['A','B'])
```

What is the asymptotic time in terms of n rows?

Comment: According to this https://towardsdatascience.com/surprising-sorting-tips-for-data-scientists-9c360776d7e pandas uses mergesort for multiple columns which has Ω(n log(n)) performance.

Comment: Isn't this something you could have just looked up?